# How to Insert Data To Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, netbeans

I want to save a "AromaNorm" into NormalisasiT1 array, but i had a error :

`AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.NullPointerException`

Can you help me?
Here the Code

```
double[] normalisasiT1 = null;
    
    double nilaipembagi = Math.sqrt(Aroma);
    
     for (int i =0; i< jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){
           double aroma1 = Double.parseDouble((String)jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2));
           double AromaNorm = aroma1/nilaipembagi;
           normalisasiT1[i] = AromaNorm;
    }
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(normalisasiT1));
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more information on NullPointerExceptions and their cause. In your case, I would guess (with the info you provided) that `jTable1.getValueAt()` is causing the exception. So the cell you retrieve might be `null` and you try to parse it. Without any more information, there is no hint on why exactly the value might be null.

Comment: I have tried checking the results through the system outprint and the data appears, but it cannot be entered into the array

Comment: Ah now I see the issue. You initialized your `double[] normalisasiT1` with `null`. Before accessing an array, you need to initialize it in java, which means, you provide the information on how big the array is going to be. For more information on arrays [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). So to fix your problem, initialize your array like `double[] normalisasiT1 = new double[sizeOfYourArray]`.

Comment: Oh its work, thanks sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should initialize the array

```
normalisasiT1 = new double [sizeOfIt];
```

the array is null so it throws NPE.